# Vue.js Methods inside the slot is not working

Tags: vue.js

It seems like the methods and data are not working inside the slot. What if we need to use the component methods inside a slot of the component?

```
<template id="child-template">
  <slot name="form">
  </slot>
</template>

<div id="events-example">
  <child>
    <div slot="form">
      <input :value="msg">
      <button v-on:click="notify">Dispatch Event</button>
    </div>
  </child>
</div>
```

and in the js

```
// register child, which dispatches an event with
// the current message
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-template',
  data: function () {
    return { msg: 'hello' }
  },
  methods: {
    notify: function () {
      alert('ok');
    }
  }
})

var parent = new Vue({
  el: '#events-example'
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ffsojvw4/

Answer (score 2):

The `methods` and `data` which you want to use on `slots`, should be bound to the parent's scope.

You could read more [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope).

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/ffsojvw4/1/